# React, setState with async updater parameter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, setstate

Does anybody know if in React it's possible to use an async updater parameter in `setState(updater)` ? I have the following code which is not working (`f` is called but the UI is not updated):

```
this.setState( async (prevState) => ({
   foo: await f(prevState.someData)
}))
```

Apparently the `async` parameter is a problem. I had to use this ugly alternate version:

```
this.setState( async (prevState) => {
   this.setState({
      foo: await f(prevState.someData)
   })      
})
```

Is there a better way to write the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Then you can `setState` twice.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    f(prevState.someData);        

    // Don't change state now.
    return {}; 
})

async f(someData) {
  this.setState(prevState) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are calling setState on a method. So why not put async on the method?

```js
async handleSomething () {
  //.. some logic

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    foo: await f(prevState.someData)
  }))
}
```

Comment: D-reaper is right - `setState()` should be pretty much an atomic operation and is a bad place for async ops. Put async fetches in a method call.

Comment: this is not allowed since `await` is inside a lambda function, and that needs to be `async` as well (the typescript compiler gives me an error).

Comment: @Omortis: I would usually move fetches out of the `setState`, the problem here is that I have a previous `setState` call, so I can't refer to `this.state` for my fetch; I am forced to use `setState(func)` in order to have access to the state.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use async inside of setState since setState needs to be a pure function with no side effects. Just do the async method before the setState call:

```
async classMethod = () => {
    let response = await someAsyncOperation(this.state.someData);
    this.setState({ someData: response });
}
```

Comment: I can't use `this.state.someData` because in my `classMethod` I have a previous `setState` call which makes `this.state` unreliable.